# Zend_Form_Element_File - I don't see this element

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I am trying to upload a photo and I have a Zend_form:

```
class Application_Form_EditUser extends Zend_Form {

public function init() {

    //$date = date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time());
    //$path = '/ImagesUsers/' .Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id.'/avatar'.$date

    $form = new Zend_Form();

    $form->setMethod('post')
            ->setName('upload')
            ->setEnctype(Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);

    $form->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

    $this->setAction('/User/edit');

    $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
        'label' => 'Name: ',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
    ));
    $this->addElement('text', 'surname', array(
        'label' => 'Surname: ',
        'required' => false,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
    ));
    $this->addElement('text', 'nickname', array(
        'label' => 'Nickname: ',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
    ));

    $this->addElement('radio', 'sex', array(
        'label' => 'Gender: ',
        'required' => true,
        'multiOptions' => array(
            'F' => 'Female',
            'M' => 'Male',
        ),
        'value' => 'F',
    ));

    $this->addElement('text', 'skype', array(
        'label' => 'Skype: ',
        'required' => false,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
    ));

    $this->addElement('textarea', 'description', array(
        'label' => 'Describe yourself: ',
        'required' => false,
        'style' => 'width: 60%; height: 70px;',
    ));


    $image = new Zend_Form_Element_File('image');

    $image->setLabel('Upload an avatar:')
            ->setMaxFileSize(10240000)
            ->setDestination('./usersImages/')
            ->setDescription('Click Browse and choose an image');
    $image->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
    $image->addValidator('Size', false, 10240000);
    $image->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif');

    $form->addElement($image, 'image');

    $this->addElement('submit', 'update', array(
        'label' => 'Save changes',
        'ignore' => true,
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $this->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl', 'class' => 'zend_form')),
        array('Description', array('placement' => 'prepend')),
        'Form'
    ));
}
```

}

Like You can see there is Zend_Form_Element_File but I can not see it on my page?? Why?

This source generate this pagesource:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/User/edit/" method="post"><dl class="zend_form">
    <dt id="name-label"><label for="name" class="required">Name:</label></dt>
    <dd id="name-element">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Test1Name" /></dd>
    <dt id="surname-label"><label for="surname" class="optional">Surname:</label></dt>
    <dd id="surname-element">
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="Test1Surname" /></dd>
    <dt id="nickname-label"><label for="nickname" class="required">Nickname:</label></dt>
    <dd id="nickname-element">
    <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="Test1NickName" /></dd>
    <dt id="sex-label"><label class="required">Gender:</label></dt>
    <dd id="sex-element">
    <label for="sex-F"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex-F" value="F" checked="checked" />Female</label><br /><label for="sex-M"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex-M" value="M" />Male</label></dd>
    <dt id="skype-label"><label for="skype" class="optional">Skype:</label></dt>
    <dd id="skype-element">
    <input type="text" name="skype" id="skype" value="" /></dd>
    <dt id="description-label"><label for="description" class="optional">Describe yourself:</label></dt>
    <dd id="description-element">
    <textarea name="description" id="description" style="width: 60%; height: 70px;" rows="24" cols="80"></textarea></dd>
    <dt id="update-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="update-element">
    <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Save changes" /></dd></dl></form>
```

But where is my upload element??? I was looking for a typo or mistake for 1 hour I check how it should be on the zend page and still I can not understand why I can not see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should't $form->addElement($image, 'image') be $this->addElement($image, 'image')?

Comment: Right. Should not be instantiating a _new_ form inside his `init()` method. All references to `$form->` should change to `$this->`.